# Why does my if condition not prevent my script from crashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, crash, typeerror

I have a script which I launch using terminal and it always works well but sometimes randomly it throws following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`

This script goes through same lines of code thouthands of times before it crashes because of this error. Here's the problematic line:

`setTimeout(function() {deleteAlert(data[This].Name, intent); }, 2000);`

How do I prevent my program from crashing? I tried doing this:

```
  if (data[This] && data[This].Name) {
    setTimeout(function() {deleteAlert(data[This].Name, intent); }, 2000);
  } else {
    console.log(colors.red('ATTENTION: ') + "alert not deleted");
  }
```

But it still sometimes throws an error at the same line. I mean it passes through `data[This] && data[This].Name` succesfully and then hits an error. How do I change this condition so that this error will not crash my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronicity.

This

```
deleteAlert(data[This].Name, intent)
```

might indeed throw an error, if `data[This].Name` is not defined, but you do a safe check two seconds before, and between the moment you do the safe check and the moment you call `data[This].Name`, `data` might change.

You should do your safe check right before you call `data[This].Name`, something like

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (data[This] && data[This].Name) {
    deleteAlert(data[This].Name, intent)
  } else {
    console.log(colors.red('ATTENTION: ') + "alert not deleted")
  }
}, 2000)
```